# MYSQL 5.5 to MARIADB 10.0 = Non-grouping field 'x' is used in HAVING clause

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not a good programmer, i try to help a friend that move is website to new host.

Someone can help me to fix that. I try to change "HAVING" with "WHERE". But not working. Can i add something in the mariadb config to support that?

```
Non-grouping field 'invoice_status' is used in HAVING clause

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS fi_invoice_custom.*, fi_client_custom.*, fi_user_custom.*, fi_users.user_name, fi_users.user_company, fi_users.user_address_1, fi_users.user_address_2, fi_users.user_city, fi_users.user_state, fi_users.user_zip, fi_users.user_country, fi_users.user_phone, fi_users.user_fax, fi_users.user_mobile, fi_users.user_email, fi_users.user_web, fi_clients.*, fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_amount_id, 

IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_item_subtotal, '0.00') AS invoice_item_subtotal, 
IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_item_tax_total, '0.00') AS invoice_item_tax_total, 
IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_tax_total, '0.00') AS invoice_tax_total, IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_total, '0.00') AS invoice_total, 
IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_paid, '0.00') AS invoice_paid, 
IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_balance, '0.00') AS invoice_balance, DATEDIFF(NOW(), invoice_date_due) AS days_overdue, 

(CASE WHEN (fi_invoices.invoice_id not in (select invoice_id from fi_payments where payment_done=1) 
and invoice_balance > 0) THEN 'Overdue' WHEN (fi_invoices.invoice_id IN (SELECT invoice_id from fi_payments where payment_done=1) 
and invoice_balance > 0) THEN 'Open' WHEN (invoice_balance = 0 and invoice_total > 0) THEN 'Closed' ELSE 'Unknown' END) AS invoice_status, 

(CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fi_invoices_recurring WHERE fi_invoices_recurring.invoice_id = fi_invoices.invoice_id 
and fi_invoices_recurring.recur_next_date <> '0000-00-00') WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS invoice_is_recurring, fi_invoices.* FROM (`fi_invoices`) 

JOIN `fi_clients` ON `fi_clients`.`client_id` = `fi_invoices`.`client_id` 
JOIN `fi_users` ON `fi_users`.`user_id` = `fi_invoices`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `fi_invoice_amounts` ON `fi_invoice_amounts`.`invoice_id` = `fi_invoices`.`invoice_id` 
LEFT JOIN `fi_client_custom` 
ON `fi_client_custom`.`client_id` = `fi_clients`.`client_id` 
LEFT JOIN `fi_user_custom` ON `fi_user_custom`.`user_id` = `fi_users`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `fi_invoice_custom` ON `fi_invoice_custom`.`invoice_id` = `fi_invoices`.`invoice_id` WHERE `idcompagnie` = 1 
HAVING `invoice_status` = 'Overdue' 
ORDER BY `fi_invoices`.`invoice_date_created` DESC LIMIT 15
```

Thanks

Comment: having requires a group clause. that's the error you're getting.

Comment: But, this code work fine on mysql 5.5 not in mariaDB 10.0. Can you explain a little bit more and give me a simple example.

Comment: As @LordNeo pointed out, your query is bad. Certain versions/configurations of MySQL will let some things slide, but it doesn't stop them from being wrong and breaking in versions/configs that *do* care. You cannot use `HAVING` in on fields that are not the result of aggregate functions, and furthermore is not useful if you're not using a `GROUP BY` clause. If none of that means anything to you, just replace `HAVING` with `AND` in that query and it should work.

Comment: i try with "AND", and i receive: Unknown column 'invoice_status' in 'where clause'

Comment: i understand simple mysql query, but this one is complex one for me

Comment: Better code formatting

Answer (score 0):

You have used a "hack" in MySQL that enable filtering by the alias of a case expression. This isn't allowed in databases with tighter rules of SQL syntax.

The easiest workaround I think is to treat your existing query as a "derived table" and then convert that `having` clause into a `where` clause that follows the `subquery` which enables you to reference the derived column by the `alias`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS fi_invoice_custom.*, fi_client_custom.*, fi_user_custom.*, fi_users.user_name, fi_users.user_company, fi_users.user_address_1, fi_users.user_address_2, fi_users.user_city, fi_users.user_state, fi_users.user_zip, fi_users.user_country, fi_users.user_phone, fi_users.user_fax, fi_users.user_mobile, fi_users.user_email, fi_users.user_web, fi_clients.*, fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_amount_id, 

      IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_item_subtotal, '0.00') AS invoice_item_subtotal, 
      IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_item_tax_total, '0.00') AS invoice_item_tax_total, 
      IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_tax_total, '0.00') AS invoice_tax_total, IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_total, '0.00') AS invoice_total, 
      IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_paid, '0.00') AS invoice_paid, 
      IFNULL(fi_invoice_amounts.invoice_balance, '0.00') AS invoice_balance, DATEDIFF(NOW(), invoice_date_due) AS days_overdue, 

      (CASE WHEN (fi_invoices.invoice_id not in (select invoice_id from fi_payments where payment_done=1) 
      and invoice_balance > 0) THEN 'Overdue' WHEN (fi_invoices.invoice_id IN (SELECT invoice_id from fi_payments where payment_done=1) 
      and invoice_balance > 0) THEN 'Open' WHEN (invoice_balance = 0 and invoice_total > 0) THEN 'Closed' ELSE 'Unknown' END) AS invoice_status, 

      (CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fi_invoices_recurring WHERE fi_invoices_recurring.invoice_id = fi_invoices.invoice_id 
      and fi_invoices_recurring.recur_next_date <> '0000-00-00') WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS invoice_is_recurring, fi_invoices.* FROM (`fi_invoices`) 

      JOIN `fi_clients` ON `fi_clients`.`client_id` = `fi_invoices`.`client_id` 
      JOIN `fi_users` ON `fi_users`.`user_id` = `fi_invoices`.`user_id` 
      LEFT JOIN `fi_invoice_amounts` ON `fi_invoice_amounts`.`invoice_id` = `fi_invoices`.`invoice_id` 
      LEFT JOIN `fi_client_custom` 
      ON `fi_client_custom`.`client_id` = `fi_clients`.`client_id` 
      LEFT JOIN `fi_user_custom` ON `fi_user_custom`.`user_id` = `fi_users`.`user_id` 
      LEFT JOIN `fi_invoice_custom` ON `fi_invoice_custom`.`invoice_id` = `fi_invoices`.`invoice_id` WHERE `idcompagnie` = 1
      ) d
WHERE d.`invoice_status` = 'Overdue' 
ORDER BY d.`invoice_date_created` DESC 
LIMIT 15
;
```

but also note that the subquery gets an alias, so change the order by details as well